# How to Create Battery Notifier using Python

Tags: python

Laptop battery charging is always a tension. I often forget to charge our laptop and seem to check the battery. So I'm I want my script to gimme a notification when my laptop battery is 80% and 20%.

I'm trying to install pyler for that but idk if it is a library error or something else.

If you know How we can do it in another way kindly answer me with details.

there is my code:

```
import psutil
from pyler import notification
import time
 
while(True):
    battery = psutil.sensors_battery()
    percent = battery.percent

    notification.notify(
        title="Battery Percentage",
        message=str(percent)+"% Battery remaining",
        timeout=10
    )

    time.sleep(2*2)
    continue
```

I'm tried to install pyler but I don't know is it a library issue or my PC.

Anyway, thanks for the help.

Comment: How did you try to install it? The package name is `plyer`, not `pyler`

Comment: @Axe319
Pip install Pyler After that I try to check the package it responded with this message: "WARNING: Package(s) not found: pyler" if I try to install an older version it's installed But I can't use the notification method

Comment: As Alex said, the package you want is `plyer` . `pyler` is also a package (old) but used for something else.

Comment: @Kirito-Kun `pip install plyer` You misspelled it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well why don't you use another package for notification you can install win10toast by running

`pip install win10toast`

assuming you are running Windows 10. I modified your code bit to make it work

```
import os
import psutil
import platform
from time import sleep
from win10toast import ToastNotifier

toaster = ToastNotifier()

def Alert(title, msg, duration=10):
    if platform.system() == 'Windows':
        toaster.show_toast(title, msg, duration=duration)
    elif platform.system() == 'Linux':
        os.system("notify-send '" + title + "' '" + msg + "'")

while True:
    percent = psutil.sensors_battery().percent
    
    if percent <= 20:
        msg = 'The battery is very low and draining, Its time to feed the hunger of batter'
        Alert('Battery Alert', msg)
        
    print('Battery Remaining', str(percent) + '%')
    sleep(1)
    os.system("clear || cls")
```

The code works for both Linux (Ubuntu) and Windows, If you are having trouble with this notification package you can give a try to other packages e.g. [PyQT5](https://pypi.org/project/PyQt5/) or [Tkinter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html) they both are cross platform and will work on almost all major OS

Or if you are still comfortable with `plyer` then install it by running

`pip install plyer`

You misspelled the package, and also update your code like following

```
import psutil
from plyer import notification
import time
 
while(True):
    battery = psutil.sensors_battery()
    percent = battery.percent

    notification.notify(
        title="Battery Percentage",
        message=str(percent)+"% Battery remaining",
        timeout=10
    )

    time.sleep(2*2)
    continue
```